# WinForms DockStyle with GroupBox and Button

Tags: winforms, docking

I have a splitter with a group box in it:

> top panel
>   ----splitter------------------------
>   group box------
>   xxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxx
>   xxxxxxxxx
>   [button]

The group box is set to `DockStyle.Fill`.  If the Button is set to `DockStyle.Bottom`, the button clings to the bottom of the panel, as I'd like it to do, but the bottom of the group box is obscured behind the button, as if the group box did not know that the button was occupying the space. The group box thinks all of its contents are visible and the scrollbar disappears.

How do I get the group box to use all space that is available but to extend no lower than the top edge of the button?

Comment: Cut the groupbox from the designer and paste it back.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the group box is set to the top: right now it thinks it's "lower" than the button, so it tries to fill the whole panel. If you set the button to be docked first, call `GroupBox.BringToFront()` second, and then set the `GroupBox.DockStyle.Fill`, it should work with the available space.